# How to change the arrow to another object in pst-optics?

Tags: pstricks, pst-optic

Consider the following example:

```
%%xelatex
\documentclass[pstricks,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-optic}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-text}

\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}(-8.5,-3)(8.5,3)
\rput(0,0){\lens[focus=3.333,OA=-10,AB=2,XO=2,xLeft=-8.5,xRight=8.5,rayColor=red]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

How can I change the arrow `AB` by an image like this: http://www.clipartden.com/_thumbspd/household/candle/candle_lit_blue.png and the arrow `A'B'` to a correspondingly scaled version of this image?

Answer (score 1):

The image has no transparent colors. The reason why it may make sense to rewdraw the red lines.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optic,pst-node,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-8.5,-3)(8.5,3)
\rput(0,0){%
  \lens[focus=3.333,OA=-10,AB=2,XO=2,xLeft=-8.5,xRight=8.5,rayColor=red]%
  \pcline[linestyle=none](A)(B)\ncput{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{candle_lit_blue}}%
  \pcline[linestyle=none](A')(B')\ncput{\includegraphics[scale=0.1,angle=180]{candle_lit_blue}}}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way such that the image scales automatically if I change the parameters of `\lens`?

Comment: yes,that is possible, but not so easy. You can get the coordinates of `A,B,A',B'` with `eg: \psGetNodeCenter{A}` But that value is known on PS level but you need it on TeX level, the reason why you have to save it in a file. See also p. 30 of the pst-node documentation