# I can't compile code that use PSTRICKS

Tags: pstricks, texmaker, windows, pspicture, pst-optic

I'm having issues trying to compile code that use the package "pstricks". When I compile the next code (which can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318763/how-to-change-the-arrow-to-another-object-in-pst-optics)) with Xelatex:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optic}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-text}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-8.5,-3)(8.5,3)
\rput(0,0){\lens[focus=3.333,OA=-10,AB=2,XO=2,xLeft=-8.5,xRight=8.5,rayColor=red]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I should have got the next output:
[image: desired_output]

but instead, I always get the next one:
[image: actual_output]

Then, when I try to compile other codes that also need the use of the package "pstricks" using Dvi -> PS and after that PS-> PDF I got warnings from Texmaker saying that:

> MikTex GPL Ghostscript
>
> 9.19: ****Could not open the file output.pdf

That's why I downloaded ghostscript 9.23 and changed the Texmaker configuration:

[image]

but it doesn't work either. What should I do? Do I have to download a new DVI viewer?

In case it's needed, I use Texmaker 4.5 on Windows 7. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have no problem here with up-to-date TL2018 and `xelatex`. Try to use an external editor and not the Built-in Viewer of TeXMaker. This can be changed in the lower right of your config image.

Comment: For an external viewer do not use the adobe reader, install Sumatrapdf, it is much more faster,

Comment: Thank you Herbert. I tried as you said but the problem is still there.

Comment: can you show the log file?

Comment: Sorry for not answering before. I was sick of it. I think I'm gonna try with Tikz drawing everything by myself. Thank you anyway Herbert!